# Usar if dentro de un template literals JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo los siguientes valores de un countdown

```
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

quiero mediante un innerHtml mostrar el valor de esas variables en mi front , pero quiero que si la longitud de de la variable es = 1 colocarle un cero antes y si no no colocarle si no el valor de la variable

como puedo colocar un if dentro del template literal para mostrar dependiendo de la condición ?
Hice esto pero me da error
Gracias por la ayuda

```
count_down_container.innerHTML = `
$ {
    if(${days.length <= 1}){
        `<p>HOLA</p>`
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Hola! recuerda aceptar la respuesta por favor, para que figure como completada. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por favor, no utilices `if` en template string. Te aconsejo el uso de operador ternario:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```javascript
count_down_container.innerHTML = `
  ${
    days.length <= 1 ? 'imprime si es verdadero' : 'si es falso';
  }
`
```

Si deseas una operación muy compleja, template string soporta el llamado de funciones, por lo tanto podrías externalizar la operación:

```javascript
function OperacionCompleja(argumento1, argumento2){
  // haces cosas complejas
  if(...)
  else if(...)
  else if(...)
  else ...

  return Tu_Resultado
}

// esto imprime el valor retornado Tu_Resultado 
template_string = `
  ${OperacionCompleja(val1, val2)}
`
```

Sin embargo, si por alguna razón extraña quieres tener una condición en el template string utilizando `if`, debes insertarla en una función autoejecutable, ya que por el scope de ejecución, template string no soporta `if`:

```javascript
count_down_container.innerHTML = `
  ${(() => {
      if(days.length <= 1){
        return `<p>HOLA</p>`
      }
    })()
}
```

Este último ejemplo es a evitar, no es una buena práctica. Además, perfectamente puedes declarar la función fuera del template string llamándola dentro, como en mi 2do ejemplo.